# Телеграм Бот на Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

Немогу никак нагуглить:((

При отправке:
Мне приходит ��������

Как мне указать кодировку ответа с сервера?
или может ктото знает Иное решение?

П.с.
Извиняюсь за "корявий" русский)

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

// replace the value below with the Telegram token you receive from @BotFather
const token = 'token';

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: true });

bot.onText(/\/echo (.+)/, (msg, match) => {

    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    const resp = match[1];
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, resp);
});

var options = {
    reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: 'значение 1', callback_data: '1' }],
            [{ text: 'value 2', callback_data: 'data 2' }],
            [{ text: 'value 3', callback_data: 'text 3' }]
        ]
    })
};


bot.on('message', (msg) => {
    const chatId = msg.chat.id;
    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'click botton', options);
});
```

Comment: Для начала приложите ваш код

Comment: Добавил  ))))))))

Comment: самое тупое, что могу предложить - проверь/поменяй кодировку файла.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой же проблемой в Visual Studio 2019. Не нашел способ решить эту проблему внутри проекта, но можно заменить кириллицу Unicode

```js
bot.sendMessage(chatId, '\u{422}\u{435}\u{43B}\u{435}\u{433}\u{440}\u{430}\u{43C} \u{431}\u{43E}\u{442}');

//Телеграм бот
```

Если хочешь красивый код, то открой js файл в VS Code и поменяй кодировку в нижнем правом углу (в моем случае нужно было изменить UTF-8 на UTF-8 with BOM)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]